# Grouping a nested map based on keys of an inner map

Tags: scala

How to group a nested map based on keys of an inner map?

```
  Map(
      "v1" -> Map("p1" -> List(3, 4),"p2" -> List(8, 10)),
      "v2" -> Map("p1" -> List(5, 6), "p2" -> List(11, 12))
    )
```

Expected output:

```
Map(
   "p1" -> Map("v1" -> List(3, 4), "v2" -> List(5, 6)),
   "p2" -> Map("v1" -> List(8, 10), "v2" -> List(11, 12))
)
```

Started with this

```
a.toList.groupBy(_._2.keys)
```

but gets grouped by set.

```
Map(
  Set(p1, p2) -> List(
    (v1, Map(p1 -> List(3, 4), p2 -> List(8, 10))),
    (v2, Map(p1 -> List(5, 6), p2 -> List(11, 12)))
  )
)
```

Comment: nice question btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach that flattens the nested `Maps` into a list of nested `Tuples` to be converted back to `Maps` via `groupBy/mapValues`:

```
val nestedMap = Map(
  "v1" -> Map("p1" -> List(3, 4), "p2" -> List(8, 10)),
  "v2" -> Map("p1" -> List(5, 6), "p2" -> List(11, 12))
)

nestedMap.toList.
  flatMap{ case (v, m) => m.map{ case (p, ls) => (p, (v, ls)) } }.
  groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).toMap)
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]]] = Map(
//   p2 -> Map(v1 -> List(8, 10), v2 -> List(11, 12)),
//   p1 -> Map(v1 -> List(3, 4), v2 -> List(5, 6))
// )
```